# Draw line in UIButton that already has png image in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I know there are lots of questions/answers about drawing in views, but this is kind of a special case because it's combining several features.

1. I'm using a UIButton
2. It has a type of Custom
3. It has a png image

So I need to keep all that, but in addition, I need to draw a line along the bottom edge (perhaps inset a few points), as shown in the picture below.

This is BEFORE the line is applied

[image]

This is AFTER the line is applied

[image]

And here are the specs for one of the buttons

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want draw this on xib, you must custom your button.

```
@interface DrawLineButton()
   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor* fillColor;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat  toLeft;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat  toRight;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat  toBottom;
   @property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat  lineHeight;
@end
@implementation DrawLineButton
   // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
   // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
   - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
   [super drawRect:rect];
    CGRect pathRect = CGRectMake(_toLeft,
                         self.bounds.size.height - _toBottom - _lineHeight,
                         self.bounds.size.width - _toLeft - _toRight,
                         _lineHeight);
    UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:pathRect];
    path.lineWidth = _lineHeight;
    UIColor* fillColor = _fillColor;
    [fillColor set];
    [path fill];
    [path stroke];
    }
@end
    //.h
IB_DESIGNABLE //Must this
@interface DrawLineButton : UIButton
@end
```

Then add the custom button to xib like this:
[image]

I hope to help you, thanks!

Comment: Wow... +10 for using IBInspectable and IB_Designable.  Never seen anyone do that before.  Even my 3rd party controls from Infragistics don't do that, and they are a huuuuugely popular component developer.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution, if you aren't sure how to draw lines in general, is to create a UILabel, set the frame to be:

`UILabel *line = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame(x,y,w,h)];`

Then, set the background color of the label

```
line.backgroundColor = [UIColor red];
```

Then, add it to the button

```
[button addSubview:line];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say since I'm not sure why you'd want to achieve this but a possible solution could be:

1. Create new UIView
2. Set alignment edges equal to the button (thus making it directly on top of the button)

[image]

3. Set view background color to transparent
4. On the newly created UIView set:

> isUserInteractionEnabled = false

Now you can draw whatever you want in that view which as you've mentioned is detailed in many other places